# How to delete roads within blocks using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I want to delete all the internal roads which exists in Block2. These roads don't have any attribute data. It is a single polygon. I need to extract only external roads. Block 2 should be made as Block 1. Block 1 is done by removing internal roads manually using "Cut polygon" tool.

I have so many block to work on. So, wanted to find an easier method

[image]

Comment: First, thanks for your concern. I want to delete all the internal roads which exists in Block2. These roads don't have any attribute data. It is a single polygon. I need to extract only external roads. Block  2 should be made as Block 1. I have so many block to work on. So, wanted to find an easy method. Please help.

Comment: Are the external roads Always wider than the internal like in your screenshot?

Comment: No, some of the internal road's width match with external road's width but don't exceed. But, mostly external roads are wider.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is very difficult since they are all the same polygon so you cant identify them by some attribute. If the external roads are wider you could try:

1. [Feature Vertices To Points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) (Advanced license required):

> Creates a feature class containing points generated from specified
>   vertices or locations of the input features

2. [Generate Near Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) with the Points as input and with the `Location parameter` checked:

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
>   in one or more feature class or layer

3. From the Near Table select rows/Point pairs with a specified small distance between them, for example all below a distance of just wider than the internal roads and then execute [XY To Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-to-line.htm):

> Creates a new feature class containing geodetic line features
>   constructed based on the values in a start x-coordinate field, start
>   y-coordinate field, end x-coordinate field, and end y-coordinate field
>   of a table.

You should now have created something like the red lines:

[image]

4. [Split Polygons With Lines](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431) on roads with the lines created:

> This modelbuilder tool allows you to split polygons with lines in a
>   geoprocessing operation

5. Select and delete polygons below a certain area. If external roads get deleted you could try deleting small polygons `and` not to very elongated (ratio of shape area and shape lenght)

Comment: I will come back once I get succeeded with your process. Thank you in advance.:)

Comment: I have got stuck at the 1st step. There are many unnecessary points/vertices generated on a single road. As these may create problem for the next step, I'm trying to remove them by using Simplify polygon tool. But, cannot remove all. I've been trying to add a screenshot in the comment section, but could not do so. Could you also suggest me how to add an image?

Comment: Then doing it like this might not be possible.

Comment: Generate Near Table with the Points as input and with the Location parameter checked:
What would be the input for "Near features", -polygon?

Comment: The Points from feature vertices as Points as both in_features and near_features ("The same feature class or layer may be used as both input and near features.")

Comment: Thanks for helping. Hope your solution worked for me. But, my data is creating more problems.